# Understanding Behaviour of Exception Handlers in java

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I have been trying to understand exception handlers in java and went through loads of articles, ending up being more confused though. I understand a thread may have its specific `ExceptionHandler(threadObject.setExceptionHandler())` which shall be checked first. If it is not having any codes then the threadGroup is `checked(threadObject.getThreadgroup().uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e))`.

Finally it looks for the default exception handler. Now two things confuse me:

1. Every Thread has a possibility to have its own defaultExceptionHandler. If then what is the scope of this?
2. If DefaultExceptionHandlers are global scoped, why is the Exception not getting handled in the code?

   ```
   public class JoinThreads {
       private volatile static int count;
       @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                   System.out.println("Thread 1 "+count);
               }
           });
           Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                   System.out.println("Thread 2");
                   throw new NullPointerException();
               }
           });
           Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);    
           t1.start();
           t2.start();
           t2.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

               @Override
               public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   System.out.println("Handler 2 "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+e.getMessage());
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

I was hoping the UncaughtExceptionHandler is going to take care of this but the thread was terminated and that code never got executed

Edit:-
Yes putting start method after setting ExceptionHandler solves the issue. Thank You. However, I want to ask something related. What is the implication of having DefaultExceptionHandler on per thread basis? If I declare it for threadObj2, how does it cover threadObj 1 as well?

Comment: `start` your threads after you set the exception handler. This is a case of a simple race condition.

Comment: Just need to swap `t2.start()` with `t2.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`. The NullPointer is being thrown before you attach your exception handler

Comment: Yes that solves the issue. Thank You. However, I want to ask something related. What is the implication of having DefaultExceptionHandler on per thread basis? If I declare it for threadObj2, how does it cover threadObj 1 as well?

Comment: `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` is a `static` method. It applies to all `Thread` instances. You don't _declare it for threadObj2_.